# Access App.method from within App.router.method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, circular-dependency

I'm building a backbone.js + require.js application and I have run into the following issue.To structure my application I have an `App.js` file which as the following contents:

```
define(function(require) {
    'use strict';

    var _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        Router = require('router'),
        ModuleManager= require('moduleManager');

    var App = function App() {
        var base = {
            router: new Router(),
            moduleManager: new ModuleManager(),
            start: function start(){
                Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
                this.router.navigate('home', {trigger: true}); 
            }   
        };
        return _.extend(
            base, 
            Backbone.events
        );
    };

    return App;

});
```

The application is started with `window.myApp = new App();`, then `myApp.start();`.

The contents of `router.js` are as follows :

```
define(function(require) {
    'use strict';

    var _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone');

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {'home': 'home'},
        home: function home() { 
            // MY ISSUE IS HERE
            App.moduleManager.add('moduleName');
        }       
    });

    return Router;
});
```

The `moduleManager` is a utility function/object for :

- Adding application modules via  `App.moduleManager.add('module')` by requiring require.js files (backbone views + collections),
- Doing some checks (e.g. ensuring the module doesn't already exist),
- Centrally storing modules in `App.moduleManager.modules`

Everything is working fine except for the following point :
**How can I call `App.moduleManager` from within `App.router.home` or any other route (`App.router.xyz`)  ?**

- Within `App.router.home`, `this` can't refer to `App` (?)
- Within `router.js`, I can't call `App = require('app')` because I would be making a [circular dependency](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) between `App.js` and `Router.js`

I'm not sure if I have a global application structure problem or if there is just a simple language construct which can work around this problem. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a *warranted* circular dependency. Using `require('app')` where `MY ISSUE IS HERE` will resolve correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that if I store a reference to `App` as `Router.app = require('app')`, i can then do things like `this.app.moduleManager` from within `Router.home` ?

Comment: If you do `Router.app = require('app')` within the `define()` itself, then you'll get `undefined` as it's a circular dependency, per the docs. However, if you defer the `require('app')` until *some time later* (i.e. in a function that is invoked later etc.) it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the object you need in the router's constructor.

But I would suggest using events.  In the route, trigger an event, then listen for that event in the app.  This leaves the router to do a single job, responding to route changes from the browser (back/forward clicks).

In router:

```
home: function() { 
    Backbone.trigger('home:show');
}
```

In app:

```
start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    Backbone.on('home:show', this.showHome, this);
},  

showHome: function(){
    this.router.navigate('home', {trigger: false}); // just update, dont trigger route
    this.moduleManager.add('moduleName');
}
```

Now if you want to change what the app is showing from your code, you can just trigger this event, instead of calling `navigate` on the router.

Some other code, maybe a menu view:

```
homeClicked: function(){
    Backbone.trigger('home:show');
}
```

This would show your home view, and also update the history.

Comment: Thanks ! I think I'll go for this as a solution. As per your answer, I find it cleaner to trigger events from the routes and use these to generate views elsewhere in the app. Things could get a little messy if I jam all view generation logic into the routes.